# XAML how to call GUI

Tags: c#, user-interface, xaml

How can I call the UI for an XAML from another class please?

Thanks.

:)

Comment: Do you mean embed a separately developed control within your form, open a new dialog, or something else?

Comment: please elaborate on your question

Comment: aha im sorry i wasnt clear. i meant to open xaml into another form

Answer (score 0):

If the XAML is a Window, instantiate the XAML class and call Show().

```
<Window x:Class="MyWindow"... >
...
</Window>

MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
w.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [x:FieldModifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905.aspx) XAML attribute to make a control public or internal like you would in Windows Forms but this is frowned upon. You should instead either create properties in your code-behind class or you should look into separated presentation patterns such as MVVM which encourage little to no direct manipulation of the UI.